# How to change Entry cursor color in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

In my application I want to change Entry cursor default color for one place. Other than that place, default cursor colors are preferred.

I can change ios cursor color using *Control.TintColor* in Entry renderer.

But when I'm trying to change android entry cursor color using colorAccent item inside the styles.xml(eg: #ffffff), it changes the cursor colors at all the places and there is no any control of it.

Is there any proper ways to achieve this both in ios and android?

Answer (score 3):

**For Android custom renderer:**

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    IntPtr IntPtrtextViewClass = JNIEnv.FindClass(typeof(TextView));
    IntPtr mCursorDrawableResProperty = JNIEnv.GetFieldID(IntPtrtextViewClass, "mCursorDrawableRes", "I");
    JNIEnv.SetField(Control.Handle, mCursorDrawableResProperty, Resource.Drawable.my_cursor);
}
```

`my_cursor` is defined in the `Drawable` folder, you can try to make it as a `Shape`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

  // colorCursors is defined in the Resources/Colors file
  <solid android:color="@color/colorCursors"></solid>
  <size android:width="2dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Hi lakmad0, did it fix your issue?

Comment: This worked so far, but I think with Xamarin Forms 4.3 this does cause a crash.

Comment: This is nice, but doesn't work with a BindableProperty ;(

Comment: You can put 0, instead of `Resource.Drawable.my_cursor` in order to have the cursor match the TextColor property